# How to show a cell data using Google Sheet Apps Script into the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've designed a custom form to input data into Google Sheet. I can input data using this form. But I want to show a specific cell data into the form. see my code attached to the Github link.
I want to show the cell(Z2) value into the input0
https://github.com/Ashraful7679/appscript/tree/master

code.gs

```
function userform() {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("userform");

  var html = template.evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Input Form");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "Input Form");


}

function intiMenu(){
    console.log("Mkkmkn");

     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var manu = ui.createMenu("Ridwan");
     manu.addItem("My Form", "userform");
     manu.addToUi();

}


function onOpen(){
 intiMenu();

}

function appendData(data){

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
  ws.appendRow([data.info1, data.info2, data.info3, data.info4, data.info5, data.info6, data.info7, data.info8, data.info9, data.info10, 
               data.info11, data.info12, data.info13, data.info14, data.info15, data.info16, data.info17, data.info18, 
                data.info19, data.info20, data.info21, data.info22, data.info23]);

}
```

userform.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

     <div class="container">

       <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="input0" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input0">Amount</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input1" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input1">Job No.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input2" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input2">Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input3" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input3">Import Duty by ctg cash/bank</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input4" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input4">Import Duty by office pay order</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input5" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input5">Shipping Agent PO Commission</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input6" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input6">Wharf rent/ Charges-1</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input7" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input7">Wharf rent/ Charges-2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input8" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input8">Freight Forwarder NOC Charges</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input9" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input9">Shipping Agent Charges-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input10" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input10">Shipping Agent Charges-2</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input11" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input11">Shipping Agent Charges-3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input12" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input12">Servay Charges-1</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input13" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input13">Servay Charges-2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input14" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input14">Depu Charges</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input15" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input15">Container Seal</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input16" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input16">CnF Assoation Fees</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input17" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input17">Labour Expenses/ Loading-unloading</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input18" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input18">Kallan Tahbill charges</label>
        </div><div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input19" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input19">B/L Verify charges</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input20" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input20">Entertainment1)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input21" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input21">Entertainment2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input22" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input22">Entertainment3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="input23" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input23">Entertainment4</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">Add
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>         
        </div>
      </div> 

     </div>


      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var input1Box = document.getElementById("input1");
        var input2Box = document.getElementById("input2");
        var input3Box = document.getElementById("input3");
        var input4Box = document.getElementById("input4");
        var input5Box = document.getElementById("input5");
        var input6Box = document.getElementById("input6");
        var input7Box = document.getElementById("input7");
        var input8Box = document.getElementById("input8");
        var input9Box = document.getElementById("input9");
        var input10Box = document.getElementById("input10");
        var input11Box = document.getElementById("input11");
        var input12Box = document.getElementById("input12");
        var input13Box = document.getElementById("input13");
        var input14Box = document.getElementById("input14");
        var input15Box = document.getElementById("input15");
        var input16Box = document.getElementById("input16");
        var input17Box = document.getElementById("input17");
        var input18Box = document.getElementById("input18");
        var input19Box = document.getElementById("input19");
        var input20Box = document.getElementById("input20");
        var input21Box = document.getElementById("input21");
        var input22Box = document.getElementById("input22");
        var input23Box = document.getElementById("input23");
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addRecord);



        function addRecord(){
                var data = {
                    info1: input1Box.value,
                    info2: input2Box.value,
                    info3: input3Box.value,
                    info4: input4Box.value,
                    info5: input5Box.value,
                    info6: input6Box.value,
                    info7: input7Box.value,
                    info8: input8Box.value,
                    info9: input9Box.value,
                    info10: input10Box.value,
                    info11: input11Box.value,
                    info12: input12Box.value,
                    info13: input13Box.value,
                    info14: input14Box.value,
                    info15: input15Box.value,
                    info16: input16Box.value,
                    info17: input17Box.value,
                    info18: input18Box.value,
                    info19: input19Box.value,
                    info20: input20Box.value,
                    info21: input21Box.value,
                    info22: input20Box.value,
                    info23: input21Box.value
                 };

                google.script.run.appendData(data);
                input1Box.value = "";
                input2Box.value = "";
                input3Box.value = "";
                input4Box.value = "";
                input5Box.value = "";
                input6Box.value = "";
                input7Box.value = "";
                input8Box.value = "";
                input9Box.value = "";
                input10Box.value = "";
                input11Box.value = "";
                input12Box.value = "";
                input12Box.value = "";
                input14Box.value = "";
                input15Box.value = "";
                input16Box.value = "";
                input17Box.value = "";
                input18Box.value = "";
                input19Box.value = "";
                input20Box.value = "";
                input21Box.value = "";
                input22Box.value = "";
                input23Box.value = "";


        } //close addrecord


      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [mcve] into the question and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi @StevenBrock! There are mainly two workarounds to fulfill your request; both using [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). The first one is to update the question with the cell content in a timely manner. Another option is to update the question after every Form response. Can you please tell me which one works better in your situation?